# How do I get edges along with the nodes I filtered in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: filter, nodes, cytoscape.js, edges

I would like to know how I can get the edges along with all the nodes which I filtered based on a specific query?

I have seen this example on Cytoscape.js page:
https://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors

```
// get node j and the edges coming out from it
cy.elements('node#j, edge[source = "j"]');
```

Now I would like to do the same with a specific query attribute which all nodes have in common along with all edges.

I tried a query along the above idea like this:

```
const query = 'node[ nodeType = "Car"]';
graphElements = cy.elements(query);
```

This gives me all nodes with nodeType="Car" but with no edges.
How can I get ALL edges along with the selected nodes query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I might have found an answer to this, apparently nodes and edges are handled separately. In order to include edges, there are several options which can be found on the [Cytoscape.js page under traversing](https://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/traversing) such as *nodes.edgesWith()*, *nodes.edgesTo()*, *nodes.connectedEdges()*, etc. etc.

So in order to for example filter by Nodes and corresponding Edges with Edge [Successors](https://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.successors) as I need it in my case, it can be done the following:

```
// Filter all nodes by nodeType Car
const query = 'node[ nodeType = "Car"]';
let filteredNodes = cy.nodes(query);

// I only want to successors of all Nodes, so I add only those and combine 
   nodes and edges with union 
const graphElements = filteredNodes.union(filteredNodes.successors());

// Apply changes on graph
cy.elements().remove();
cy.add( graphElements );
```

This is what I came up with, if anyone has something to optimize please let me know. I am still figuring out Cytoscape.js myself.

Comment: Do you really want all successors of your filtered nodes to remain in the graph? I tried out your code with a dagre graph, there it seems a little pointless to perform the filtering in the first place. Can you elaborate a little more about your goal?

FYI, I would implement it like this:  

`let filteredNodes = cy.nodes('node[ type = "car"]');
cy.nodes().not(filteredNodes).remove();`

Comment: Yes, I want to show all successors of my filtered nodes in the graph, it is like that by design, I want to allow for getting an overview over a specific graph section by including surrounding successors of nodes. Would cy.nodes().not(filteredNodes).remove() keep the unwanted attached edges and only remove the unwanted nodes?

Comment: The `.not()` part is basically a negative `.union` where you filter out every node not present in your filtered nodes collection. That way, you remove all nodes not in the collection and all edges not connected to nodes in the collection. Every edge with suorce and target within the filteredNodes stays in the graph. If you want, I can create a live example as an answer below.

Answer (score 5):

In order to filter nodes with connected edges, you can use the `.remove()` function together with the `.not()` function, resulting in every node not in the provided collection to be deleted, along with every edge from and to a node not in the collection:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px",
        "border-color": "black",
        "border-opacity": "1",
        "border-width": "10px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "$node > node",
      css: {
        "padding-top": "10px",
        "padding-left": "10px",
        "padding-bottom": "10px",
        "padding-right": "10px",
        "text-valign": "top",
        "text-halign": "center",
        "background-color": "#bbb"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ":selected",
      css: {
        "background-color": "black",
        "line-color": "black",
        "target-arrow-color": "black",
        "source-arrow-color": "black"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "n0"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n3",
          type: "car"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n7"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n11"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n12",
          type: "car"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n15"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n16"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "n0",
          target: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n2",
          target: "n7"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n2",
          target: "n11"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n2",
          target: "n16"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n3",
          target: "n4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n3",
          target: "n16"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n4",
          target: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n4",
          target: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n6",
          target: "n8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n8",
          target: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n8",
          target: "n10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n11",
          target: "n12"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n12",
          target: "n13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n13",
          target: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n13",
          target: "n15"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "dagre",
    padding: 5
  }
}));

cy.off("click");
cy.on("click", function(event) {
  let filteredNodes = cy.nodes('node[ type = "car"]');
  cy.nodes().not(filteredNodes.union(filteredNodes.successors())).remove();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```